# Received bitcoin but can't send

Tags: multibit

I am new and using multibit 0.5.14. I have received 2 bitcoins in one transaction, and 0.005 in another. However, after over an hour they are still not spendable. I checked the status and it says "seen by 4 peers Pending/Unconfirmed. When I check on blockchain.info, there are 17 confirmations for that block. How do I know if something has gone wrong? Is there something else I should do to make my bitcoin 'spendable' or do i just have to wait it out longer?

Comment: What does it say about your specific bitcoin address at blockchain.info?

Comment: Have you restarted the client?  There is a chance that your client experienced some form of network hiccup and isn't updating it's block chain.  Close the application and restart it.

Answer (score 2):

You can click Tools-> Reset Blockchain and Transactions.